# How can I check the quality of my probabilities?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, quality-control

I have a data set where the number of accidents are given together with the probability (assumed to be correct) that the number of accidents is less than 4.

The task is to calculate the probabilites for accidents less than 3 and less than 5.

I assumed normal distribution and did this. However, I had to make some assumptions and I dont know which set of assumptions gives "best" probabilities.

How can I test the quality of my probabilities? I do have the actual number of accidents, but the idea is to use my finding for the future accident calculations, where the probability of less than 4 accident will **always** be given.

Comment: Since numbers of accidents are small counts, a normal distribution is guaranteed not to work.  It's unclear what you are really trying to accomplish, since you state you have the actual numbers of accidents.  Could you explain more about these data, how they were collected, and how they are intended to be used?

Comment: That it accidents is not important. The data is fake. It contains number of accident, and the probability that less than 4 accidents occur. Number of accidents looks normal distributed. The task is to calculate the probability of <3 and less than <5. This is however done with some assumptions. Then I need to somehow compare the probabilites and see "how they are" or if I should use other mean and sd for my calculations

Comment: Please visit http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts so that you can edit and comment on your question.  I *guarantee* that the number of accidents is not well described by a Normal distribution, because these have to be whole numbers within a relatively small range. This suggests you might not be accurately describing what you have or what you want to do with it.  Your references to "some assumptions" *etc.* are too vague to help people find good answers.